# recursive method to get ftp directoryList

Tags: c#, ftp, treeview

I try to "create" a recursive method, which copy the ftp directory list to a treeView.

I allready tried to do that, but it is more quick & dirty as clean & simple.

Here you can see my Code-Snippets:

```
public void connectToServer(string pServerIP, string pServerPort, string pUsername, string pPassword)
    {
        _serverIP = pServerIP;
        _serverPort = pServerPort;
        _username = pUsername;
        _password = pPassword;

        string ftpServerPath = "ftp://" + pServerIP + ":" + pServerPort + "/";
        try
        {
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpServerPath);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(pUsername, pPassword);
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

            secondLevelDirectotyList = new List<string>();

            int i = 0;
            TreeNode rootTreeNode = tVDirectories.Nodes.Add("/");
            Console.WriteLine("/\n");
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                secondLevelDirectotyList.Add(reader.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("...: " + secondLevelDirectotyList[i]);
                i++;
            }

            reader.Close();
            response.Close();

            getFTPDirectoryList(secondLevelDirectotyList, 0);
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The following Exceptions occurs:\n" + ex.Message, "Exception occurs", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void getFTPDirectoryList(List<string> pTopLevelDirectoryList, int pDirectoryListIndexer)//string pFTPPath)
    {
        //List<string> 
        string ftpServerPath = "ftp://" + _serverIP + ":" + _serverPort + "/" + pTopLevelDirectoryList[pDirectoryListIndexer];//pFTPPath;
        try
        {
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpServerPath);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_username, _password);
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

            thirdLevelDirectoryList = new List<string>();

            int i = 0;
            TreeNode ftpServerDirectory = tVDirectories.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(pTopLevelDirectoryList[pDirectoryListIndexer]);//pFTPPath);
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string streamFTPPath = reader.ReadLine(); //Ließt die Zeile des Streams aus
                thirdLevelDirectoryList.Add(streamFTPPath); //Fügt den gesamten Pfad in die String-Liste
                Console.WriteLine("...........: " + thirdLevelDirectoryList[i]);

                string newTreeNode = streamFTPPath.Substring(streamFTPPath.IndexOf(@"/") + 1);
                ftpServerDirectory.Nodes.Add(newTreeNode); //Fügt nur den Unterordner- oder Unterdatei-Namen in die Ansicht ein
                i++;
            }

            reader.Close();
            response.Close();

            //rekursiv
            pDirectoryListIndexer++;
            try
            {                    
                getFTPDirectoryList(pTopLevelDirectoryList, pDirectoryListIndexer);
            }
            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
            {
                // start next level Directory List
                //pDirectoryListIndexer = 0;
                //getFTPDirectoryList(thirdLevelDirectoryList, 0);
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The following Exceptions occurs:\n" + ex.Message, "Exception occurs", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I don't get the point to browse through the ftp folders.
You also may noticed that I work with ftp-protocol the early first time.
For example: I don't know whether I should open a request every time the ftp-ListDirectory-Command is send.

I want something like this:
root/
...folder1
......file1infolder1
...file2
...folder2
......file3infolder2

I hope you can understand me :D
and I am also sry for my bad english.

Comment: I got it. I'll post the solution tomorrow, but I think a recursive GetFTPDirectoryList-method isn't efficient, caus it take a long time to check every file on a server or NAS. So I'll change it. I think the best way to solve it, is to check a folder once the user clicked on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution for a recursive method, which list all files and folders from a ftp-path,
**BUT**
it is ***unefficient*** and it is impossible to use!!!!
If you only have five folders, this method will work, but if you have more than ~five folders the method won't end - sure it will be finished SOME DAY..

So for everyone, who read this:
Think about your Idea to use a recursive method to list the ftp-directory!
**You better should send the NLIST-ftp-command once the user "opens" a folder.**

```
private void FtpNlistRecursive(string pPath)
    {
        try
        {
            DirectoryListOfCurrent = new List<string>();
            _ftpServerFullPath = "ftp://" + _serverIP + ":" + _serverPort + "/" + pPath;
            string newItem = "";

            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_ftpServerFullPath);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_username, _password);
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                newItem = reader.ReadLine();
                string shortItem = pPath.Substring(pPath.IndexOf(@"/") + 1); // Aus "Ornder1/Datei1.txt" wird "Datei1.txt"
                if (!shortItem.Equals(newItem))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (pPath.Equals("/"))
                        {
                            DirectoryListOfCurrent.Add(newItem);
                            directoryListOfAll.Add(newItem);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string completePath = pPath + newItem.Substring(newItem.IndexOf(@"/"));
                            DirectoryListOfCurrent.Add(completePath);
                            directoryListOfAll.Add(completePath);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
                    {
                        //bei ZB "Datei3.txt" gibt es kein "/", somit einfach ignorieren
                    }

                }
            }
            reader.Close();
            response.Close();

            foreach (string item in DirectoryListOfCurrent)
            {
                FtpNlistRecursive(item);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionOccurs(ex);
        }
    }
```